# Networkx add a node with an already existing name

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx, relationship

I am currently trying to display relations between objects of a generic Node class using NetworkX. As it is possible for two nodes to have multiple edges between them, I am trying to implement this using a MultiGraph. The Node class I made contains an attribute called "caption", which I want to display ontop of the node. Each node also has the attribute "id", which is a number unique to the node. However, multiple nodes having the same caption causes an issue.
In this example, I want Node Y and Z to each have a connection to new nodes called "A" and "B". Note that there are two Nodes with the name "A" and two with the name "B". I envision that to look somewhat like this:
[image: example graph]

The following code produces an image where the nodes called A and B are treated as being only one node each:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define Node class
class Node:
    def __init__(self, caption, id, parent_id, parent_connections, children):
        self.caption = caption                          
        self.id = id                                    
        self.parent_id = parent_id                      
        self.parent_connections = parent_connections    
        self.children = children                        


G = nx.MultiGraph()
# create all nodes for the example
node_x = Node(caption="X", id=1, parent_id=None, parent_connections=[], children=[])
node_y = Node(caption="Y", id=2, parent_id=1, parent_connections=["first connection"], children=[])
node_z = Node(caption="Z", id=3, parent_id=1, parent_connections=["first connection"], children=[])
node_a_y = Node(caption="A", id=4, parent_id=2, parent_connections=["first connection", "second connection", "third connection"], children=[])
node_b_y = Node(caption="B", id=5, parent_id=2, parent_connections=["first connection"], children=[])
node_a_z = Node(caption="A", id=6, parent_id=3, parent_connections=["first connection"], children=[])
node_b_z = Node(caption="B", id=7, parent_id=3, parent_connections=["first connection"], children=[])

all_nodes = [node_x, node_y, node_z, node_a_y, node_b_y, node_a_z, node_b_z]
# fill the children lists with every node's children
for node in all_nodes:
    for other_node in all_nodes:
        if other_node is not node and other_node.parent_id == node.id:
            node.children.append(other_node)
# add the nodes and edges to the MultiGraph G
for node in all_nodes:
    G.add_node(node.caption)
    for child in node.children:
        for i in range(0, len(child.parent_connections)):
            G.add_edge(node.caption, child.caption, length=10)
# draw the Graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_color="r", node_size=100, alpha=1)
ax = plt.gca()
for e in G.edges:
    ax.annotate(e[1],
                xy=pos[e[0]], xycoords="data",
                xytext=pos[e[1]], textcoords="data",
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color="0.5",
                                shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=rrr".replace("rrr",str(0.3*e[2])),
                                ),
                )
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting graph]

Furthermore, adding the node objects directly to G's nodes and edges instead of just adding the captions creates this result:
[image: other resulting graph]

this seems to be what I am looking for, but unfortunately the objects themselves are being used as a caption instead of the caption attribute.
Is there a way of making networkx use a certain attribute of the given object as a caption? If there isn't, what else could I do to reach my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes need to have distinct (and hashable) IDs. By default, networkx uses these ID as the labels of the nodes. However, you can specify other labels using the `labels` attribute. The `labels` values can have duplicates (unlike the node IDs).

```
nx.draw(nx.Graph([(0, 1)], labels={0 : 'a', 1 : 'a'}); plt.show()
```

[image]

See also: `nx.draw_networkx_labels`.

---

Regarding the second part of your question:

> but unfortunately the objects themselves are being used as a caption instead of the caption attribute

To be precise, the `__repr__` method of your `Node` class is used for the node labels.

> Is there a way of making networkx use a certain attribute of the given object as a caption?

You can override the default `__repr__` method to return the caption attribute instead.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.caption
```